# Close Fragment onKeyListener in EditText

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

Maybe this is a small issue for someone more experienced than me (I work with Android since two months), but I really can't figure it out why the same line of code inside a OnKeyListener doesn't work.

For example, I'm able to close my Fragment by clicking the Quit button of the Fragment and I can go back to my Activity.

```
btnAbbrechen.setOnClickListener {
            activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.remove(this)?.commit() // works
        }
```

Anyway, if I use the same code into a EditText field from the same Fragment, the Fragment won't close.

```
        eTPalFussNr.apply {
            requestFocus()
            setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { _, keyCode, event ->
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
//                    activity?.supportFragmentManager?.popBackStack() // nothing happens
                    activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.remove(PalFussFragment())?.commit() // nothing happens
                    return@OnKeyListener true
                }
                false
            })
        }
```

I followed all the posts with similar issues on SO, but couldn't find the right answer. So, please tell me what am I missing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are creating a `PalFussFragment` in remove function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `this@PalFussFragment` instead of try to remove a new instance of `PalFussFragment()`

```
requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .remove(this@PalFussFragment)
    .commit()
```

Prefer use `requireActivity()` instead of `activity?` directly to make sure fragment is always attached to activity.